# Understanding a statement about palindromic numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, terminology, integers, palindrome

I have the following statement:

"Palindromes starting with $n$ such that the sum of the digits of the product of the factorial of $n$ and reverse of $n$ is equal to the center digit."

And I am trying to understand what it says (I am not a native English speaker). It gave the numbers $595$ and $11911$ as examples. I do not get it.

---

I aksed my prof for another example and he gave me $696$ with the following explanation:

$$6!\cdot6!=518400; 5+1+8+4+0+0=18; 1+8=9.$$

Comment: The problem in quotes is not worded in a clear way, at least to me. I cannot tell what it is asking either.

Comment: Yea, I am a native speaker and it is still a piss poor statement.

Comment: An awful description ! Does the center digit apply to $n$ or the number itself ? Also, I could not get the given numbers as solutions.

Comment: I thought so. I edited another example with explanation given by my prof.

Comment: It's hard to parse, but I interpret it something like this: let $\bar{n}$ be the "reverse" of $n$ (taking the digits in opposite order), and let $d$ be a digit. Consider a palindrome of the form $n\ldots d\ldots \bar{n}$ such that $$d = \text{sum of digits of}\;\;(n!\cdot\bar{n})$$ Your prof's hints suggest that the formula should actually be $$d = \text{sum of digits of}\;\;(n!\cdot\bar{n}!)$$ ("factorial" should be "factorials"?), and that "sum of digits" means iteratively totaling the digits until a single digit remains. None of this is clear from the description given.

Comment: Would that then be not a quite boring property ? Every factorial from $3!$ on is divisible by $3$, so the final digit sum is always $9$ (for $n\ge 3$) , hence we basically just have the palindromes with an odd number of digits and center digit $9$ (with a few exceptions). Or do I miss something ?

Comment: Is this the source: http://oeis.org/A082941 ?